# C++(11) Timer: Accumulate until idle

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

I'm facing a rather basic problem that I'd like to implement in C++(11 is Ok) using only standard libs.

Assume a function "Message()" which can be called any given number of times, after it's not called for a given time I want to trigger an action. For example:

```
Message();
Message();
Message();
Message();
sleep(10); <-- the idle time triggers an action 
Message();
```

Hope this makes sense.

The way I implemented this so far is using a combination of an async while loop and a condition variable which I pulse every time a message comes in. Once the wait for the CV times out I take action.

In pseudo-code:

```
void Message(){
  unique_lock ul(M);
  new_message = false;
  CV.notify();
}

...

future = std::async([]{ 
  do {
    unique_lock ul(M);
    new_message = false;
    got_message_within_time = CV.wait_for(ul, 20ms, new_message==true);
  } while got_message_within_time;
  // Got a timeout here...
  time_to_take_action(); 
});

...

Message()
Message() 
Message()
sleep(10)
```

I'm not convinced this is the most elegant solution out there, anyone has better suggestions? All in all the fundamental statement I want to implement is: "once I stop calling you, do something"

Any help/suggestion is welcome

Thanks !

Comment: If you have something that cal poll a timer reset in Message frequently, then you don't need threading. Otherwise, I think you've written a decent solution. Although it's not very resource friendly

Comment: If polling is acceptable, a more simple approach might be a watchdog thread and an atomic timestamp updated on each message. The watchdog checks the last timestamp and takes action if it's grater than a threshold.

Comment: David, Xvan, the watchdog approach with polling might work actually, but I'd need it to run continuously where the message bursts can be quite sparse. I'd have to think about it.

Some context: I'm implementing a home automation thing on a RPi: the buttons I'm using keep on sending their address for as long they're pressed (I know, don't tell me... I didn't make those ;-) ). I'd like to translate these into address/duration of press

Comment: Pseudo code is not useful.  Threading code is tricky, and often errors within threading code require actual code to detect.  At least one translation of your above pseudo code to code is fundamentally flawed.  I believe at least one translation to code is not.  I have no idea which version you have in mind, as your code is missing important details.

Comment: @yakk, Pseudo code makes it comprehensible. Both the new_message flag, the mutex and the future are stored in a shared object if that is the flaw you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I use a method similar to what you do, but I leave a monitoring thread running.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono;

time_point<steady_clock> lastMessage(steady_clock::now());
bool shutdown(false);

void InactiveMessageLoop(){
    while(!shutdown){
        if((steady_clock::now() - lastMessage) > milliseconds(1000)){
            std::cout << "Are you still there?" << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
    }
    std::cout << "No hard feelings." << std::endl;
}

void Message(){
   lastMessage = steady_clock::now();
   // do stuff;
}

int main(){
    std::thread MessageThread(InactiveMessageLoop);

    Message();
    Message();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(5000));

    Message();
    Message();

    shutdown = true;

    if(MessageThread.joinable()) MessageThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could look into sending a signal, but it's probably just as effective to just interlace your code with a call to a message check function, since its considered bad practice to put business logic inside of a signal function.

Edit:  I added the join at the end.

Comment: Something to watch out for if you use this code in Windows.  Some versions of Visual Studio generated code will deadlock if the main thread exists before the child threads.